# TargetDataLine does not stop in plugin project

Tags: java, javasound, javax.sound.sampled

I'm making a program that records from the microphone and saves to an audio WAVE file. The code executes successfully, but I noticed that the program never end after the record has been completed in a plugin project.

So I tried this code (shown below), but the program never ends. Why? How can I resolve this?

```
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.TargetDataLine;


public class RecordTeste {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TargetDataLine line;

        final AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, 16000, 16, 1, 2, 16000, false);
        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);

        try {
            line = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
            line.open(format);
            line.start(); 


            line.stop();
            line.close();
        } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Thank you!

Comment: When you debug it, on which line your program stays?

Comment: The program reaches to the end of try catch.

Comment: So then your program ends, doesn't it??? Or what else do you mean by "the program never ends"?

Comment: I'm sorry, what I mean is that the program reaches the end of try catch but the console does not end, then the program doesn't terminate for some reason.

Comment: I am still confused. How do you launch your program? What do you mean by "the console does not end"? And does your program save anything?

Comment: If I run this code in eclipse environment, then I must click on the terminate button to end the program. When we run a program, eventually, he will terminate right? This is not the case and I don't know why.

Comment: Well, you said it reaches the end of try catch... Well, what version of Java you use? Can you use Java 7? In this case move your definition `TargetDataLine line` after `try` like this: `try (TargetDataLine line = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);) { the rest of your code here }` and remove the command `line.close();` completely.

Comment: There is currently a flow in your design so when there is an exception then the line is not closed. This might cause the problem I quess... but stil I do not understand what you mean by "program does not stop" but "it reaches to the end of try catch".

Comment: I got it. The class works in a normal java project but not in a Plugin Project, but I've launched this code as a Java Application. I'm sorry for omitting this detail. There is solution?

Comment: Have you tried it with the changes I suggested?

Comment: Yes! In a java project I've tried with Java 6 and 7 successfully, but I needed in a plugin project.

Comment: In a plugin project you probably need to have some other way of launching than the `main()` method. My suggested changes could not have worked in Java 6!!!